# Fastest Way to Generate x Number of Random Variables

Tags: matlab, vectorization, computation-theory

```
index = [10 100 1000 10000 100000]
```

Let's say I wanted to generate `10, 100,...,100000` (corresponding to index above) exponential random variables with parameter `1/10`.  I of course did this with a `for` loop and with the command for example

```
x = exprnd(0.1,100,1)
```

One can also generate the exponential random variables from a uniform random variable with

```
x = -10*log(u)
```

In this method, I first generate the uniform random variables then plugged the vector, `u`, into the previous equation.  This method is faster in terms of computation time.

How might I speed this process up?  Could I do this with vectorization, that is, without for loops?

Comment: What exactly is the desired output? 5 different vectors, containing the number of elements specified in `index`?

Comment: The desired output would be a 5 x 2 matrix containing the time it took to generate each of the vectors.

Comment: So your problem is to generate the vectors, or to measure the time it takes to do it?

Comment: Both actually.  Using tic-toc and for loops, my output resembles :



times =

    0.1154    0.0010
    0.0079    0.0048
    0.0629    0.0416
    0.5325    0.4122
    5.4873    4.1574

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
expFun = @(size)exprnd(0.1,size,1);

index = [10 20 30 40];
data = cellfun(expFun,mat2cell(index,ones(size(index,1),1),ones(1,size(index,2))),'UniformOutput',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd wold create one long vector in the length of `sum(index)` and then partition it into the different sizes I want.

This would be the fastest way.

Comment: It could very well be, but then I can't compare how fast it was for 10 vs 10, 100 vs 100,...with respect to the two different methods for generating exponential random variables.